# Can I still use AuditReader when I have my own listeners in Envers?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, hibernate-envers, audit-trail

I am trying to do conditional auditing with Envers so, according to [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/devguide/en-US/html/ch15.html#d5e4275), I turned off default Envers event listeners and instead registered my own subclasses.

Now I'm trying to read audit tables with AuditReader but it throws an exception saying that Envers (default) listeners were not correctly registered.

Can I still somehow use the default audit reader in case I'm only turning audit on/off in certain situations? I'm not altering the tables nor doing anything manually in my listener, I'm just checking some conditions and then calling methods from superclass or not.

**UPDATE:**
It turned out that for AuditReader to work, listeners need to implement EnversListener interface. Problem solved.

Comment: What version of Envers? Stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that Envers tries to read the AuditReader from the listeners assigned to the Hibernate session. If your post insert listeners does not implement AuditEventListener, you'll need to build the AuditReader manually. This is how I implemented it in our solution, loosely based on the Envers implementation:

```
private AuditReader getAuditReader(final Session session) {
    SessionImplementor sessionImpl;
    if (!(session instanceof SessionImplementor)) {
        sessionImpl = (SessionImplementor) session
                .getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    } else {
        sessionImpl = (SessionImplementor) session;
    }

    return new AuditReaderImpl(this.versionConfig, session, sessionImpl);
}
```

The input Session is a Hibernate session. The versionConfig variable need to be provided somehow. This Envers configuration object can be created in your custom listener's init function like this:

```
public final void initialize(final Configuration configuration) {
    versionConfig = AuditConfiguration.getFor(configuration);
}
```